# Rails: How to generate xml with repeating nodes from ruby hash using to_xml method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I want to generate below XML format from ruby hash using to_xml method

```
<commands>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <meta>
                <engine>A</engine>
                <wheels>4</wheels>
            </meta>
            <meta>
                <engine>B</engine>
                <wheels>2</wheels>
            </meta>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <schedules/>
    <cmds/>
</commands>
```

There is a `<meta>` tag inside  tag which is repeating twice. What should be the structure of the hash to generate this format using to_xml method?

Comment: Things that repeat would be in arrays.

Comment: `to_xml` is not the right tool if you're looking to generate a specific XML output. Its more of a kludge to provide XML responses the `to_xml` way with a minimum of effort. Use a view, builder or nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using by using "compare_by_identity" method of hash. using compare_by_identity method we can have same keys in hash so this way i can have same key in hash which helped me in creating the XML output which i have posted in this question..